# Generating Elementary Geomerty illustrations from declarative description

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dsl, constraint-programming

I am looking for general method or algorithm can render geometric objects in the most declarative way that is possible.

For example, using Quil libruary (Clojure binding for Processing language) or any other similar libruary I can simply draw lines and triangles.

But in this case I need to explicitly specify coordinates of points. It leads to manual computations and other complications.

So I am looking for or a way or a libruary to render illustration from declarative descripion. Declarative description in this case contains some named shapes and relations between them.

```
point A, B, C
line a, b
a contains A, B
line b intersects a at B
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: @Prune Okay, I changed request from libruary to the general method. I think it is dumb, because I ask very specific question. But I am sure, that SO users would prefere to close my question than to think about this problem a little.

Comment: @Prune If you look at selected cause for closing question, you can see, that my request does not falls at description. This question does not lead to "opinionated answers", because I "described the problem". A libruary in this case is a way to solve specific problem.

Comment: Understood.  I withdrew my close vote.  What you're asking is currently in the realm of artificial intelligence (inference systems), since there may be no solutions, a unique solutions, a handful of solutions, or infinite solutions within a variety of range types.